# Postgres function always returning true even though SQL command returns false

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write an SQL function to return true only when a certain number of rows match a given condition, otherwise false. I have successfully come up with the SELECT statement which has the desired behavior:

```sql
SELECT count(*) > 32 FROM data WHERE run = run AND [OTHER CONDITIONS];
```

This succesfully works:

```
btl_qa=# SELECT count(*) > 32 FROM data WHERE run = 127 AND [OTHER CONDITIONS];
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

However, when I try to create a function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pass(run bigint) RETURNS boolean AS $$
    SELECT count(*) > 32 FROM data WHERE run = run and [OTHER CONDITIONS];
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

it always returns true:

```
btl_qa=# SELECT pass(127);
 pass 
------
 t
(1 row)
```

I assume it has something to do with the fact that the select statement is returning a table instead of a boolean, but I'm not sure how to get just the boolean value.

Comment: The condition `run = run` is true for all rows in the table. Don't name your function parameters and/or variables the same as the table column.